# Join query to select fields from 2 tables

Tags: sql

I created 3 tables viz Employee, Department and EmpDept.

1) Employee Table fields are

> :- EmployeeID(Primary Key) , Fname,
>    Lname, Age, Salary, Address

2) Department Table fields are :-

> DepartmentID(Primary Key), DeptName , DeptLocation

3)EmpDept table fields are :-

> ID(Primary Key), EmpId(Foriegn Key reference Employee table)
>       , DeptID(Foreign key references Department table)

I want to perform following operations :-

a) Select all the fields from table Employee and Department 
b) Deleting a particular department also deletes all the employees from Employee table belonging to that particular department.

I am not getting what fields to include in 3rd table(i.e EmpDept) and how to apply join to select columns

*My attempt*

```
create procedure EmpDept2 
as 
Begin 
select Employees.EmployeeID
      , Employees.FirstName
      , Employees.LastName
      , Employees.Age
      , Employees.CreatedDate
      , Employees.LastModifiedDate
      , Employees.ModifiedBy
      , Employees.Active
      ,Department.DepartmentID
      , Department.DeptName 
from Employees, Department inner join EmpDept 
on EmpDept.EmpId = Employees.EmployeeID 
on EmpDept.DeptId= Department.DepartmentID
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ??? Please read here [`How to ask a question on Stackoverflow`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create procedure EmpDept2 
as 
Begin 
select Employees.EmployeeID
      , Employees.FirstName
      , Employees.LastName
      , Employees.Age
      , Employees.CreatedDate
      , Employees.LastModifiedDate
      , Employees.ModifiedBy
      , Employees.Active
      ,Department.DepartmentID
      , Department.DeptName 
from Employees inner join EmpDept 
on EmpDept.EmpId = Employees.EmployeeID 
inner join Department 
on EmpDept.DeptId= Department.DepartmentID
END
```

JOIN Two table at a time and then the condition ON what you are joining them, Then add One by one other tables again specifying the condition on which you want to join them.

Comment: It's inside PL/SQL, so you need an INTO clause.

Comment: Try now I missed the `END` cluase

Comment: This query would likely suit indexed-views more than procedures as the content seems relatively static anyways.